# Check one column to see if it contains a value from another column and highlight duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need a formula to highlight all rows in a column if the value exists in another column.
So if I have Column A and it has 100 rows 20 of them just have the word cat, 20 dog, 20 bird and 40 lizard. and in Column B I only have 1 row that says cat and one row that says bird I need all the cat and bird rows in column A highlighted. I have been looking for something like this for a while now and can not find it anywhere.

Comment: take a look at the built-in feature `conditional formatting`. no need for VBA. [This page](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html) at www.contextures.com (not my page) has a good intro.

Comment: This could work if i was to figure out how to use a range. I am using Format cells that are equal to. But when i paste in a range it does not highlight anything

Comment: For future reference, they way you were doing it is the easiest way if you only need to color for 1 matching item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. Select all cells to be formatted
2. Create new conditional formatting rule
3. Select the last option **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
4. In the formula box enter this: `=VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)=A1`
5. Click **Format** button and choose the color you want
6. Click **OK**

This is what it should look like when you are done.

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to let you know! Your answer has saved a lot of my time. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I struggled a bit with this, because it didn't explain what the fields for the vlookup were as my columns that I wanted to highlight were starting at H2, so I changed all A's to H, and all 1's to 2's, which that third argument in vlookup neededed to be 1, even though documentation says:
col_index_num: Required. It represents the integer specifying the column number of the table_array that we want to return a value from.
I guess I don't know what that actually means.