# Highlight a cell in excel if that value is found in another table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am able use a couple different formulas within the conditional formatting to highlight a cell if that cell's values (text in this case) are found within another column in the same worksheet-e.g., [Check one column to see if it contains a value from another column and highlight duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454608/check-one-column-to-see-if-it-contains-a-value-from-another-column-and-highlight).

However, I would like to be able to see if a cell's value is present within and entire table (multiple columns) not just the first column. When i use something like this (=VLOOKUP(A1,B1:T50,1,FALSE)=A1) it only looks for a match in the first (B) column and ignores the rest of the table. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` instead of `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: Vlookup only indexes on the first column, col 2 onwards are results columns.